# JSF Bound HtmlPanelGrid not shown

Tags: jsf-2

I use a managed bean to generate an HtmlPanelGrid, and then bind it in the xhtml file, like so

```
    <h:panelGrid id ="questions"  binding="#{ui.generatedComponents}" />
```

On this page is a form, with a dropdown, and whenever a value is selected, it shows the page. However, whe something is selected, every other (static i.e in xhtml page) component is shown, but the binded component is never shown.

However, if I re-request the page in the browser, it does show them.

Mucho confusing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `binding`, you need to make absolutely sure that the property behind this attribute is **exclusively** been used by this component in the current view. The managed bean should *not* be in the session scope, because it would then share the same property between multiple views (browser windows/tabs) in the same session. It should of course also not be in the application scope. The managed bean should be at highest in request or view scope. The view scope makes the most sense for this particular purpose.

The getter method of the property behind `binding` should also contain **no** business code. It should solely return the property, nothing more. Any initialization needs to be done in the (post)constructor or an (action)listener method of the backing bean class. Any manipulation of this component property needs to be done in an (action)listener method of the backing bean class.

Not doing so may result in awkward behaviour.

Comment: Awkward indeed...  It already is set to request scope and I have moved the business code to the postconstruct.  However, the problem i believe is down to the 'setter' method in the original sessionscoped managed bean (which is injected via managed property to the requestscoped managed bean). It seems to be called **after** the postconstruct method, so the UIComponent is built on old data.... should I use a value/action listener?

Comment: I think so. Can you advise how I can obtain the 'new' data that is being posted to the session bean, from inside the postconstruct? Using the requestparametermap???? Or something else?

Comment: Just do the job in (action)listener method. The one which is bound to the `action` or `listener` attribute of your command/ajax component.

Comment: Hey there - sorry to be awkward. i have put the logic in a valuechangelistener, but the request scope bean is created, and the UIComponent for binding is requested through the getter even before the valuechangelistener is called. Therefore even if i use the listener, the value (and subsequent HtmlPanel) is already retrieved before I can change it.....? Or am i wrong in this?

Comment: It's a reference, not a copy. Java is OO, not procedural. Do not focus too much on the getter/setter being called. Ignore them. Focus on creating/manipulating/storing it the right way. Create it in (post)constructor, manipulate it in (action)listener methods and store it in a request or view scoped bean. That's all.